# call a c# functions in cshtml when Ajax.BeginForm completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

so have an Ajax.BeginForm that call a PartialView
and return a view (which I'm using it for filtering the products)

but I want to change the main view **Model** too

I mean after the Ajax.BeginForm got completed
i want to make **ViewBag** in the **PartiaView** action

and after that when Ajax.BeginForm got completed 
then call a function in cshtml to update the main view model 
with that **ViewBag**

how can I do that

at the end this is my goal:

```
@functions{
public void ChangeModel(){
    Model.Prod = ViewBag.Prod //forget about the casting !
}
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetStations", "Trains", new { area = "Site" }, new AjaxOptions
{
    OnSuccess = ChangeModel(),
}, null))
```

Answer (score 0):

OnSuccess is a JavaScript callback function,

the C# code will be

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetStations", "Trains", new { area = "Site" }, new AjaxOptions
{
    OnSuccess = 'mySuccessCallback',
}, null))
```

Your controller will return something like this

```
return Json(new { Prod = ViewBag.Prod, ... }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

the JavaScript will be

```
function mySuccessCallback(data, status, xhr) {
    var newProdValue = data.Prod; // passed as model from backend

    // ... display the new value anywhere with JS or jQuery
}
```

Comment: no the action return partialview  i want to get it with viewbag

Comment: no problem view it with javascript like this :
***function mySuccessCallback(data, status, xhr) {
    var newHTML = data;
$('#myDiv').html(newHTML);
}***

Comment: i want to get it with viewbag and set it in view Model , I don't want to show anything

Comment: you can't do this with ***ViewBag*** you can use ***TempData*** to do this